# Progress Icon in button type submit error

Tags: formio

I am creating two buttons using form.io which is the type of Submit.
But here I am facing an issue when clicking on any button all the buttons on that page enables progress icon.

How can disable that progress icon or how can I enable for only the one which is clicked[image: when i click on approve the progress spinner is coming for both reject and approve same when i click on reject]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using css , display none for the image